# Fedora Realtek USB WiFi Driver Installation

Tags: networking, fedora, drivers, reboot, modprobe

So I have a realtek usb wifi adapter, and it uses the driver: `rtl8822bu`

[The GitHub site](https://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8822bu) has the driver.

So I `git clone https://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8822bu.git` Then

```
cd rtl8822bu 
sudo make 
sudo modprobe cfg80211 # as this is what the readme said 
sudo insmod rtl8822bu.ko # also from readme
```

Lastly, `sudo make installfw` I did get Fedora recognize the usb device and connect to wifi through it, but then after every reboot it gets wiped and I have to do the `modprobe` and `insmod` again. Is there a way for me to have it auto start every time at boot?

[This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/8j5jvz/new_to_fedora_need_to_install_wifi_driver/) said there is a way for me to "# make the driver load on every boot", but I don't know if this applies of what name I should change it to. You can download the git to see what name I should use or do to get it to load at every boot, I am new to Fedora, so I honestly know not how to do this.

Thanks before hand to all of ya!

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu. I've been using this project's drivers for over a year and they've never let me down.

Comment: I would say that it is a good author, but I already got the one I linked to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author only described additional information. It's still about building a kernel external module as described officially there:

[Building External Modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html)

starting with:

> ```
> $ make -C <path_to_kernel_src> M=$PWD
> ```

But the module author appears to have made a few things to simplify user's life, and a simple `make` will build because of various variables set and then used [there](https://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8822bu/blob/master/Makefile#L459):

> ```
> all: modules
>
> modules:
>   $(MAKE) ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KSRC) M=$(shell pwd)  modules
> ```

The `-C` option will continue inside kernel source/headers makefiles having additional targets. To finalize the installation, one should still follow kernel's documentation:

> Then to install the module(s) just built, add the target
> “modules_install” to the command:
>
> ```
> $ make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD modules_install
> ```

That's what you have to add, but it should be run as root (or prepend `sudo` , or guess the destination and copy files manually), since only root can write to the target destination (`/lib/modules/...`):

```
sudo make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD modules_install
```

And then you might also have to rebuild modules dependencies (assuming here it's with the current kernel), again with root privileges:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

USB should be plug-and-play, so I'm not sure the Reddit suggestion is then needed, you could try without first and if needed add it.

Manually, if you don't want to remove/reinsert the USB NIC right after installation, you can now do:

```
modprobe rtl8822bu
```

NB: don't expect this to be enough if UEFI secure boot is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, everything worked out alright after the reboot and the module/driver loaded itself.
Though that it worked well, I would want to ask another question, what did the 
>sudo depmod -a
has to do after modules_install? I can't seem to understand the point of doing that, regardless though, I did run it anyways. I hope you won't mind elaborating on that point.

Comment: That's to get modprobe to load other modules if needed. Imagine this module requires a module doing checksums, it will be added in dependencies. modprobe is mostly run from the kernel.

Comment: And if I understand correctly, running the depmod -a, is to make sure other dependencies get loaded up for the wifi dongle module/driver so to make sure it has everything it needs to work, and upon reboot, this should happen automatically then? Btw, thanks so much again for the detailed answer, I was looking for a long time.

Comment: that's it yes . Note that my answer has nothing Fedora related. There might be Fedora specific ways to package the result, but I wouldn't know much about this.

Comment: I don't think it matters anymore if it worked lol. I wish you a nice day and hope this post can help others!